# Broke my javascript with if else

Tags: javascript, php

I feel like I'm missing something really simple, so I've decided to get over my stubbornness and actually ask a question here instead of wasting any more time.

I've started making my personal blog from scratch (for the personal challenge and learning experience of it) not too long ago and I'm currently on writing the code for email validation; the standard send email with token & email GET variables. It works properly (hooray), but there's one problem that was introduced when I decided to add email validation to the back end. The ajax call is still successful and returns the right string; however, once I added an else if statement to my javascript to handle showing error messages for invalid email that gets (or is forced) through, it seems to act as though there isn't a curly bracket--my success boolean which determines the success/failure of my alert is set to false and the string displayed to the user is also not as I intended. Here's my code and a screenshot to illustrate:
*I changed the if..else to a switch to see if it would change anything--it didn't.

```
    //JAVASCRIPT
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
    if(request) request.abort;

    var message = ""; 
    var success = false;
    var formMessageBox = document.getElementById("form-message");

    var form = $(this);
    var inputs = form.find("input");
    var data = inputs.serialize();

    inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "php/form.php",
        type: "post",
        data: data
    });

    request.done(function(data) {

        var submission = data;

        switch (submission) {
            case "success":
                message = "You're good to go! You'll be receiving an email shortly from <strong>my_email</strong>, just to make sure everything's in the green";
                $("form").innerHTML = "";
                success = true;
                break;

            case "fail":

                message = "Seems this email is already in my database; you may have submitted twice, or somebody might have hijacked your email--don't worry, it's more than likely the former.";
                success = false;
                break;

            default:

                message = submission;
                success = false;
                break;

        }
    });

    request.always(function() {

        inputs.prop("disabled", false);

        if(success) {
            formMessageBox.classList.add("alert-success");
            if (formMessageBox.classList.contains("alert-danger")) formMessageBox.classList.remove("alert-danger");

        }
        else {
            formMessageBox.classList.add("alert-danger");
            if (formMessageBox.classList.contains("alert-success")) formMessageBox.classList.remove("alert-success");
        }

        formMessageBox.innerHTML = message;

    });

    event.preventDefault();

})

//PHP

<?php

if(!$_POST["email"]) {
    echo  "Please enter an email address";
    exit(0);
}

if($_POST["email"] AND !filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Please enter a valid email address";
    exit(0);
}


$dbconn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username", "password", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) die("There seems to be something wrong. Sorry, try again later");

require_once('CryptoLib.php');
$token = CryptoLib::randomString(16);

$name  = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "user";
$email = $_POST['email'];

$emailTo="$email";  
$subject="Web Devs' Corner Verification";   
$body="http://www.allen-mcintoshii.com/webdevscorner/php/verify.php?conf-token=".$token."&email=".$email;   
$headers="From: my_email";  

$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `conf_token`) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$token')";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
if ($result AND mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers))  echo "success"; 
else echo "fail"; ?>
```

[My 'successful error'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae5Pr.png)

To be honest, it's not all that critical, but it definitely is not what I intend to happen, so why not use this little quirk as a chance to learn something? Thanks in advance to everyone who decides to help me out.

Comment: Try adding logging statements to see which of your callbacks fires first, `done` or `always`!

Comment: Juh, haven't thought about that, thanks I'll definitely try that out now

Comment: @deceze I tried--twice just to make sure--the done callback fires first as I expected.

Comment: is there css in the file

Comment: If it is there. Check it

Comment: I know this might sound stupid, but is that your **literal** js code?

Comment: There is a css file, but the alert classes I left  to bootstrap so I highly doubt that is the issue. @GGG yes, that is my js code (I did write it myself too if that helps); unless you mean something else by 'literal'.

Comment: @AllenMcIntosh By literal I mean exactly what is in the file. Can you do a `console.log` on `typeof submission` on the `request.done` please?

Comment: I thought of that too; it returns as a string. And that is my js as it is in my file, why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, while I was trying to do something similar for another small project, I actually found my own soloution. I'll just leave it here in case anyone finds themselves in a similar predicament.

```
//PHP
<?php

session_start();

$errors = array();
$errors[] = "You have been successfully signed up! Welcome to your diary!";
$min_chars = 8;
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (!$email) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter an email address.";
}

if ($email AND !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors[] =  "Please enter a valid email address";
}

if (!$password) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter a password.";
}
else {
    if (strlen($password) < $min_chars) $errors[] = "Your password must be at least $min_chars characters";
    if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`', $password)) $errors[] = "Your password is required to have at least on capital letter";
}

if (!$errors[1]) {
    $dbconn = mysqli_connect(args) //just hiding what needs to be hidden here;
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) die("There seems to be something wrong. Sorry, try again later");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `email` ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $email)."'";
    $results = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbconn, $query));

    if ($results != 0) $errors[] = "We're sorry, that email is already in our database, did you mean to log in?";
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $email)."', '".password."')";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
        $_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($dbconn);
    }
}

if ($errors[1]) session_destroy();
echo json_encode($errors);
?>

//Javascript
$(document).ready(function() {

var msgBox = $("#message-box");

$("#signup").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.post("signup.php", formData, function(data) {

        var success = data.length == 1 ? true : null,
            numErrors = data.length,
            errors = "";

        if (success != null)    {
            msgBox.addClass("alert-success");
            msgBox.removeClass("alert-danger");
            msgBox.html(data[0]);
        }

        else {
            msgBox.addClass("alert-danger");
            msgBox.removeClass("alert-success");                
            var i;
            for (i = 1; i < numErrors; i++) {
                errors = errors + "<li>" + data[i] + "</li>";
            }

            msgBox.html("<ul>" + errors + "</ul>");
        }
    }, "json")
})

$("#login").submit(function(e) {
    $.post()
})

})
```

Instead of trying to return different strings in the event of pass/fail, I decided to let PHP return one JSON object at the end no matter what. By placing the success message at the very top and pushing any error messages  as the code moves along, it becomes way easier to just check if the return data's length is only 1 or greater. If it's 1, there were no errors and everything went fine; else, a for loop iterates through all the returned messages starting from the second one, effectively printing out all errors occurred. I hope this helps anybody who found themselves in a similar bind